# Prometheus counter increase from the beginning of the calendar day

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Can we write a query in Prometheus which will work similarly to this one:

```
sum(increase(request_count_total[1d]))
```

but with the difference that we want the increase of the counter not from the beginning of the full 24 hours interval but from the beginning of the calendar day instead (calendar day that contains a concrete points on the graph).